# libpng16.so: undefined reference to `inflateValidate'

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I'm just reporting. I faced an issue while tried to build libpng on Amazon Linux (Red Hat based). But I got following error:

```
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/pngfix contrib/tools/pngfix.o  ./.libs/libpng16.so -lz -lm
./.libs/libpng16.so: undefined reference to `inflateValidate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked environment variables and they were set normally. `nm` tool displayed that `inflateValidate` was in zlib library exports. I hope my solution (see below) will help somebody and will save his time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add `LDDFLAGS` to `./configure`:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib -lz"
```

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Running, on Lubuntu 16-04 on a 64 bits box, my solution was to specify the path to the `zlib` library.

First, build the `zlib` library:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install
make
make install
make clean
```

Then, build the `libpng` library by specifying the dependency with the `--with-zlib-prefix` option:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-zlib-prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install
make
make install
make clean
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was solved by configuring CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS. In my case:

CPPFLAGS=/usr/zlib/include
LDFLAGS=/usr/zlib/lib

./configure --prefix=<path_optional> CPPFLAGS=/usr/zlib/include LDFLAGS=/usr/zlib/lib

make
make install
make clean